# Inject Tree Typeorm Repository in Nestjs

Tags: mysql, typescript, tree, nestjs, typeorm

is it possible to inject Tree Typeorm repository into Nestjs?

I didn't find anything online or in the sources that would help me here.

Or would it be better at this point to initialize nestjs and Typeorm seperat and not use the injection of nestjs and the TypeOrm module of Nestjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself right after I posted this. :D
You just have to inject the `EntityManager` with `@InjectEntityManager()` and then you can access `.getTreeRepository()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Entity)
              private readonly treeRepository: TreeRepository<Entity>,
              ) {
  }

  async findAllNested(): Promise<Entity[]> {
    return await this.treeRepository.findTrees();
  }
```